# How to append element to another element using php

Tags: domdocument, php

I am trying to append the elements into my new created node in Domdocument.

I have something like

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
     $dom->loadHTML($html]);
     $xpath=new DOMXpath($dom);
      $result = $xpath->query('//tbody');

      if($result->length > 0){
          $tbody = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tbody');
          $table=$dom->createElement('table');
           $table->appendChild($tbody);
       }
```

My tbody doesn't have table tag and it is like

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>cell</td>
       <td>cell</td>
       <td>cell</td>
    </tr> 
    ….more
</tbody>
```

I wanted to wrap it with a `table` tag.

My codes don't work and it gave me error like

> PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to DOMNode::appendChild() must be an instance of DOMNode, instance of DOMNodeList given,

How do I solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery / raw javascript?

Comment: I can't because it's an email

Comment: It's called *getElement**s**ByTagName* not a single one. Use `->item(0)` to get the first element by that name. The rest looks fine. Just read the error message, it basically says so (list instead of element).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `$tbody` is not a single `<tbody>` element; it's a *collection* of elements -- you are "getting elements by tag name", and there can be many. There is also absolutely no reason to use XPath if all you want is to find elements by tag name.

Do this instead:

```
$tbodies = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tbody');
foreach ($tbodies as $tbody) {
    $table = $dom->createElement('table');
    $tbody->parentNode->replaceChild($table, $tbody);
    $table->appendChild($tbody);
}
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/BmqDi7)**.

Comment: +1; Also right comment about xpath, it's superfluous in this case.

Comment: It works as expect but it seems like my table cell has no border. I add $table->setAttribute('style','border:2px solid #8C8C8C;text-align:center;table-layout:fixed; border-collapse:separate;') and only the table itself has border but not the table cell. I am not sure what happened +1

Comment: @FlyingCat: Border is not inherited by child elements. You can use CSS to easily apply border to all cells, but with inline styles you need to apply it to each cell individually.