# Weird issue with table on domdocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I have a very weird issue with table cell.

My previous post
[How to append element to another element using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476343/how-to-append-element-to-another-element-using-php)

My code is like the following

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html]);
$tbodies = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tbody');
foreach ($tbodies as $tbody) {
    $table = $dom->createElement('table');
    $table->setAttribute('width',500);
    $table->setAttribute('style','border:2px solid #8C8C8C;text-align:center;table-layout:fixed; border-collapse:separate;');

     $tbody->parentNode->replaceChild($table, $tbody);
     $table->appendChild($tbody);
 }
$returnText .=$dom->saveHTML();
```

From my previous pose, I got my answer but it seems like the new html table doesn't have border in the table cell.

So my table like

```
 ___________
|cell  cell |
|cell  cell |
|___________|
```

but I want every cell has border.
I am sure my original html table cell has no inline style addressing cell border too.

Can anyone helps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no border on the cells because in css the `table` tag is styled separately from the cells `td` or `th` tag. See here: http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/tables/html_table_border.cfm

edit: Better link.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used domdocument but i see this line :

```
$table->setAttribute('style','border:2px solid #8C8C8C;text-align:center;table-layout:fixed; border-collapse:separate;');
```

Instead of adding style attribute that will stylish your table and not td cells , try to add a class for your table that will stylish both table and cells :

```
$table->setAttribute('class','test');
```

and add a css file or a style that containts your class :

```
 <style type='text/css'>

    .test{
       border:2px solid #8C8C8C;
       text-align:center;
       table-layout:fixed;
       border-collapse:separate;
     }

    .test th,.test td{border:2px solid #8C8C8C;}
 </style>
```